# Detect sentence from a JSON file and extract related entities

Tags: python, json

I have a dataset that represents one sentence of the parsed text and looks like this:

```
[{
    "address": 1,
    "ctag": "Ne",
    "feats": "_",
    "head": 6,
    "lemma": "Ashraf",
    "rel": "SBJ",
    "tag": "Ne",
    "word": "Ashraf"
}, {
    "address": 2,
    "ctag": "AJ",
    "feats": "_",
    "head": 1,
    "lemma": "Ghani",
    "rel": "NPOSTMOD",
    "tag": "AJ",
    "word": "Ghani"
}, {
    "address": 3,
    "ctag": "P",
    "feats": "_",
    "head": 6,
    "lemma": "in",
    "rel": "ADV",
    "tag": "P",
    "word": "in"
}, {
    "address": 4,
    "ctag": "N",
    "feats": "_",
    "head": 3,
    "lemma": "Kabul",
    "rel": "POSDEP",
    "tag": "N",
    "word": "Kabul"
}, {
    "address": 5,
    "ctag": "N",
    "feats": "_",
    "head": 6,
    "lemma": "born",
    "rel": "NVE",
    "tag": "N",
    "word": "born"
}, {
    "address": 6,
    "ctag": "V",
    "feats": "_",
    "head": 0,
    "lemma": "شدشو",
    "rel": "ROOT",
    "tag": "V",
    "word": "شده_است"
}, {
    "address": 7,
    "ctag": "PUNC",
    "feats": "_",
    "head": 6,
    "lemma": ".",
    "rel": "PUNC",
    "tag": "PUNC",
    "word": "."
}]
```

In `"Adress": 7`, the `"ctag":"PUNC"` present end of the sentence. My original dataset contain several sentences. First, I want to detect that this is sentence one, from each sentence that ends with `PUNC` or `.`, I want to check first, in the first sentence to extract the special `two or three` entities like `'ctag'='Ne'` and for the next word, `'ctag'= 'N'`, then the relation between these two entities are `'rel'= 'NVE'` and then it should be stored in a list.

What I did:

```
# read file
with open('../data/parse.txt', 'r') as myfile:
    obj = json.load(myfile)
for w in obj:
    if w['ctag'] == 'Ne' and w['rel'] == 'SBJ':
        n1.append(w['word'])
    if w['ctag'] == 'N' and w['rel'] == 'SBJ':
        n6.append(w['word'])
    if w['ctag'] == 'N' and w['rel'] == 'MOZ':
        n2.append(w['word'])
    if w['rel'] == 'NVE' and w['ctag'] == 'N':
        n3.append(w['word'])
    if w['rel'] == 'MOZ' and w['ctag'] =='Ne':
        n4.append(w['word'])
    if w['rel'] =='MOS' and w['ctag'] == 'Ne':
        n5.append(w['word'])
    if w['rel'] == 'OBJ' and w['ctag'] == 'N':
       n7.append(w['word'])
```

It means that from `27` address I found this number of entities:

```
rel=SBJ & Ne: ['Ashraf']
rel=MOZ & Ne ['President', 'Capital', 'Lecturer', 'University']
rel=MOS & Ne ['Ashraf', 'Kabul', 'Ahmad']
rel=MOZ & N ['Afghanistan', 'Afghanistan', 'Kabul']
rel=NVE & N ['born']
rel=SBJ & N ['Kabul']
rel=OBJ & N ['Located']
```

What I want:
- It should find the first `"."` or `"PUNC"`, and then in this first sentence, check the entities, so I found that `if word['ctag'] =='Ne' and word['rel'] == 'MOZ':` then these are the relation entities, the rest are the named entities, like `subject & object`. 
- then it should go to the next `"PUNC"` and retrive `Ne` and `rel`.

--> The output I expected from each sentence:
   `(e1, relation, e2)`--> `(Kabul, located, Afghanistan)`

Comment: The question is unclear, mostly because your sample output does not seem to match your input. Define your wanted result so that it matches your input data, and define your input data so that it covers all possible cases.

Comment: @Tomalak, I added the output, you can see the question, I completely changed it into English: output:-  `(entity1, relation1, entity2)` as `(Kabul, located_in, AFG)`